# How do I calculate weighted degree distributions with igraph in R?

Tags: r, igraph

Consider a dataframe `df` where the first two columns are node pairs and successive columns `V1`, `V2`, ..., `Vn` represent flows between the nodes (potentially 0, implying no edge for that column's network). I would like to conduct analysis on degree, community detection, and other network measures using the flows as weights.

Then to analyze the graph with respect to the weights in `V1` I do:

```
# create graph and explore unweighted degrees with respect to V1
g <- graph.data.frame( df[df$V1!=0,] )
qplot(degree(g))
x <- 0:max(degree(g))
qplot(x,degree.distribution(g))

# set weights and explore weighted degrees using V1
E(g)$weights <- E(g)$V1
qplot(degree(g))
```

The output from the third qplot is no different than the first. What am I doing wrong?

**Update:**

So [`graph.strength`](http://igraph.sourceforge.net/doc/R/graph.strength.html) is what I am looking for, but `graph.strength(g)` in my case gives standard degree output followed by:

```
Warning message:
In graph.strength(g) :
At structural_properties.c:4928 :No edge weights for strength calculation,
normal degree
```

I must be setting the weights incorrectly, is it not sufficient to do `E(g)$weights <- E(g)$V1` and why can `g$weights` differ from `E(g)$weights`?

Comment: Re the difference between ``g$weights`` and ``E(g)$weights``: ``g$weights`` looks for a *graph* attribute named ``weights``, ``E(g)$weights`` looks for an *edge* attribute named ``weights``. Incidentally, there is also ``V(g)$weights``, which looks for a *vertex* attribute named ``weights``.

Comment: The graph.strength documentation (linked in question now) indicates it looks for the _graph_ attribute named weight, however in my example once I fix the type to E(g)$weight, `graph.strength` works as expected. Why? Does it first search for the graph attribute and then the edge attribute?

Comment: Looking for a graph attribute would not make sense since such an attribute would be attached to the graph itself and not the individual edges. `graph.strength` looks only for the edge attribute. The documentation says "if the graph has a `weight` edge attribute...", so I guess it is clear that you need an edge attribute here.

Comment: Right, I'll eventually learn to read. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The function `graph.strength` can be given a weights vector with the `weights` argument. I think what is going wrong in your code is that you should call the weights attribute `E(g)$weight` not `E(g)$weights`.

Answer (score 4):

I created an equivalent `degree.distribution` function for weighted graphs for my own code by taking the `degree.distribution` code and making one change:

```
graph.strength.distribution <- function (graph, cumulative = FALSE, ...)
{
  if (!is.igraph(graph)) {
    stop("Not a graph object")
  }
  # graph.strength() instead of degree()
  cs <- graph.strength(graph, ...)
  hi <- hist(cs, -1:max(cs), plot = FALSE)$density
  if (!cumulative) {
    res <- hi
  }
  else {
    res <- rev(cumsum(rev(hi)))
  }
  res
}
```

Comment: This is indeed very useful. Would you mind adding it to the `igraph` wiki as well? This is the link to the appropriate wiki page: http://igraph.wikidot.com/r-recipes

Comment: Thank you for sharing! Not sure if this is the right place to ask, but, do you have an example of how to use this graph.strength.distribution() function? I checked https://rdrr.io/github/abnormally-distributed/rsfcNet/man/strength_distribution.html but there is an error in installing that package due to my version of R studio, so referring back to this thread.