# For each node compute the weighted sum of out going edges

Tags: r, igraph

I would like to sum the value of the edges of each vertex in a directed weighted graph and assign the result as vertex attribute to an igraph dataframe.

Minimal example:

```
  library(igraph)
  From<-c(rep("CAN",5),rep("AUS",5),rep("BEL",5),"ARE",  "AUT", "CHL")
  To <- c("ARE", "AUS", "AUT", "BEL",  "CHL", "ARE", "AUT", "BEL", "CAN",     "CHL","ARE", "AUS", "AUT", "CAN", "CHL", "BEL","CAN","AUS")
  Value<-c(91797,  3228225,  1304649,    86381,     7448,  1867011,      496547,    79204 ,  645396,  3141317, 18397745,   300065,    28532,      182493,
  159825 , 3069572,   357998,   125969)
  minimal.examp<-data.frame(From,To,Value)
  minimal.graph<-graph_from_data_frame(minimal.examp)
```

Comment: There is another question/answer that addresses this point, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8344565/how-do-i-calculate-weighted-degree-distributions-with-igraph-in-r/). I'm flagging a duplicate question, ok?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I calculate weighted degree distributions with igraph in R?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8344565/how-do-i-calculate-weighted-degree-distributions-with-igraph-in-r)

Comment: Also, your code doesn't run.

Comment: thanks. graph.strength is indeed what I was searching